# Use processed output from stdin as a replacement string in Sed

Tags: sed

Following command gives me the output I want:

```
$ sed '/^<template.*>/,/<\/template>/!d;//d' src/components/**/*.vue | html2jade
```

in that it processes each `template` containing html into it's `pug` equivalent.

Would it be possible now to somehow replace the originally found html in all those files, with this now
processed output? There is also some other content outside `template` tags, which should stay as it is,
namely some `script` and `style` tags.

Comment: Use the `-i` option to `sed` to replace the contents of the file with the processed version, instead of writing to stdout.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: How would you know which files need which processed output?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Each file gets the result of editing that file.

Comment: At the end of that pipe line, after `html2jade` command, you don't have filenames, so how would you append another `sed - i` after that, maybe I did not understand what you meant? Or did you suggest having command substitution in the replacement part?

Comment: I don't know what `html2jade` is, but I thought you just wanted to update the files instead of using that.

Comment: I just looked up `html2jade`, why would you want to replace the originally found HTML with that? It's not HTML.

Comment: No, you misinterpreted my question. It's not that easy.

Comment: Because, it becomes html, after webpack processes that file. It's vue single file component.

Comment: As is, your requirement is confusing. Improve your Q by making things explict (from front-to-back) and include *small* sample data, and required output from same. The replacment string only needs to be `<t>stuff</t>` (or similarly small). Does reading `man tee` help/give ideas? Good luck.